# Azure app service WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE work for web but not work for sqlite

Tags: azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I have followed this blog to change azure app service time zone and it's work for my asp.net mvc web. blog link : 
[Louis-Charles Gagnon Blog | Microsoft Azure App Service - Set TimeZone for your web application](http://www.louischarlesgagnon.com/post/azure-app-service-set-timezone-for-your-web-application)

#### what problem i have met

but now it's not work for sqlite under the App_Data folder,e.g: the time in asp.net mvc is `2020-02-11 09:36:23` but it's `2020-02-11 01:36:41` on sqlite

#### what i have did

- azure app service `Configuration` add  name `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` , value `Taipei Standard Time`
- sqlite is under `App_Data` folder
- sqlite sql is `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now')`